# Handling conflicts on Index when columns are nullable in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

Say I have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id SERIAL, first VARCHAR(10), second VARCHAR(10), other VARCHAR(10));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_index ON test (first, second);

INSERT INTO test (first, second, other)
  VALUES ('lorem', null, 'old');
```

If I populate this column and have the second field in the index be null, but what to upsert on conflicts where null=null, how can I do this?  Currently I'm not getting a conflict when the upsert value is null as well.

```
INSERT INTO test (first, second, other)
  VALUES ('lorem', null, 'new')
ON CONFLICT (first, second)
  DO UPDATE SET
    other = EXCLUDED.other;
```

I will get an output of something like this:

```
1   lorem   (null)  old
2   lorem   (null)  new
```

This works if I set the second column to any value, but there's no conflict when they're null.  Why?  And how can I fix this?

Comment: Because comparing `NULL = NULL` does not yield `True` [ NULL is not a value, so it can not compare equal to any value or non-value]

Comment: And the only sane way to solve this is to make the field(s) NOT NULL. (it are strings, so empty strings can serve the same purpose)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an index on an expression.  What often works is:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_index ON test (COALESCE(first, ''), COALESCE(second, ''));
```

Of course, this assumes that `''` is not a valid field value.  You can always put something else in . . . such as `'<null>'`.

Comment: This worked for me. My nullable column was float and -1 was an ineligible value so I used coalesce(mycol, -1). One nuance is that the on conflict column listing also needs the coalesce statement to work or you get a warning.